# Use of VkSubpassDependency vs semaphore?

Tags: vulkan

I am following this vulkan tutorial: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation
 I am currently at the subpass dependency subsection. In it the author says that because image layout transition may happen before we acquire an image from the swap chain, we need to use VkSubpassDependency as below so that the renderpass will wait at the fragment shader output stage.

```
VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
```

However, the author also has this code before

```
vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphore };
VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];
VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphore };
submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;
if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit command buffer");
}
```

What this code does is that the fragment shader stage will not start until we are able to actually acquire an image from the swapchain (imageAvailableSemaphore makes sure of that). To me, these two pieces of code are doing the same thing, which is to make sure that the fragment shader stage does not start until we are able to acquire an image. Why is that?

PS: I also have trouble understanding the stagemask and access mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subpass dependency says that the transition from `initialLayout` to the first layout happens between `srcStageMask` and `dstStageMask` of the respective synchronization scopes.

The semaphore wait with `pWaitDstStageMask` says the semaphore will be waited no later than the stage (and by nature of semaphore wait block any subsequent execution until the wait finishes.

You cannot skip the semaphore, because `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` is not a queue operation and the semaphore (or the fence) is the only way to know the presentation engine does not need the image anymore.

And you cannot skip the subpass dependency, because skipping it is the equivalent of providing `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT`. That means the layout transition (which can be a write access) can be executed at any point. And if your `pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, that means the presentation engine may still be reading the image, while your work already tries to change the image layout.

You could use `pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` (resp. `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT`) with no barrier\dependency. But that means "wait on the semaphore first thing", which then blocks everything. Including the parts that do not even need the swapchain image (like vertex processing). That may be suboptimal on some platforms, and there's no reason to do it.

I should add that synchronization commands do not really go through pipeline stages. They only define the dependency between their synchronization scopes. What is happening between the Semaphore wait and Subpass dependency is an *execution dependency chain*. The Semaphore defines a dependency between the PE and the `COLOR` stage. The Subpass Dependency defines a dependency between the `COLOR` stage and the layout transition. The stages thus chosen **do** form an *execution dependency chain* between those two sync primitives. And such chain forms a transitive property; i.e. it acts as one singular dependency between the PE and the layout transition.

Comment: I have some questions. 
1/ The VkSubpassDependency specifies the image layout transition will happen sometimes between srcStageMask and dstStageMask. But in the tutorial they are the same VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT. Does that mean that the transition will always happen at fragment shader stage?

Comment: 2/The semaphore is to ensure that fragment shader stage does not begin until we acquire an image, and the subpass dependency is to ensure that the image layout transition (which happens before the subpass begin?) won’t begin until the fragment shader stage starts(which by then we must have acquired an image). The renderpass could have happened before however, going through the vertex shader stage because this stage doesn’t require writing to the image. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @HenryWise Firstly, "fragment shader stage" would be `VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT`. Secondly, specifically it means: "the layout transition happens-after all commands in `VK_EXTERNAL`(i.e. stuff before render pass) reached `srcStageMask` and happens-before any commands in subpass `0` reached `dstStageMask`".

Comment: ad 2: yea, something like that. Simply, there are four uses of the image in this code: PE reading the image, layout transition, load operation, and output from the fragment shader. We want to order them, and make sure none of them overlap with the other.

Comment: The load op, by definition happens-before the first use, so that's OK. And the load op happens in `COLOR_ATT_OUTPUT` (for color attachment), so that's our `dstStageMask`. In `srcStageMask` we want to block the semaphore, but not any other work (such as some unrelated Compute or Copy), so are choices are anything but `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. With the semaphore wait we want to block the first use of the image, but not anything else (such as Vertex processing) so we need in `pWaitDstStage` `COLOR_ATT_OUTPUT` or `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. So the only optimal stage to use in both cases is `COLOR_ATT_OUTPUT`.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you mean. Can each subpass go through the entire pipeline by itself? Because that means the image layout transition can occur after at COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT stage of subpass VK_EXTERNAL but before COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT stage of subpass 0. And then the semaphore makes sure the COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT stage of VK_EXTERNAL won't start until we successfully acquire an image.

Comment: @HenryWise A healthy intuition is that each action command can go through a pipeline by itself. It is the lifecycle of the command (and of the suboperations it defines) after all. The sync commands are not really action commands though, and do not really have this lifecycle. They only define the dependency between the two synchronization scopes. What is happening in our case between the semaphore wait and the subpass dependency is called an _execution dependency chain_.

Comment: PS: I feel basically we are getting to the point where the whole sync tutorial\theory is needed to properly explain, and that is not something I can fix here in this limited format on SO... I will try to add something to the answer though.